# Safari only - menu appears in the wrong place

Tags: html, css, menu, safari

Here is a link to my [website](http://www.renoized.com). 
In Chrome, Opera, Firefox and even the dreaded IE it displays fine, the way I want it to. In Safari, however, the menu appears 11px lower than where it should.

I have honestly no idea what I have done wrong, how would I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `display:inline-block;` (Safari: `line 707`)

**Try This:**

```
.main-navigation li a {
    text-align: left;
    color: #C9C9C9;  
}
```

**Instead of:**

```
.main-navigation li a {
    text-align: left;
    display:inline-block;
    color: #C9C9C9;
}
```